# typescript: make class objects iterable

Tags: typescript

How to make Typescript objects iterable?
In Python 3 I can do

```
class EndlessCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count
```

but what is the Typescript equivalent of this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Javascript supports [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), typescript doesn't add much to it: [typescript Iterators and Generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html).

Your code can be done like this in javascript:

```
function* generator() {
    let counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        yield counter++;
    }
}

var iterator = generator();
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 0
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 1
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 2
```

---

#### Edit

You can do the same with a class:

```
class Counter implements Iterator<number> {
    private counter = 0;

    public next(): IteratorResult<number> {
        return {
            done: false,
            value: this.counter++
        }
    }
}

let c = new Counter();
console.log(c.next().value); // 0
console.log(c.next().value); // 1
console.log(c.next().value); // 2
```

---

#### 2nd Edit

The first solution with the generator works well with the for/of loop:

```
function* generator() {
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < 5) {
        yield counter++;
    }
}
for (let i of generator()) console.log(i);
```

Prints 0 to 5, however, to do that with an instance you'll need to do:

```
class Counter implements Iterable<number> {
    private counter = 0;

    public [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return {
            next: function() {
                return {
                    done: this.counter === 5,
                    value: this.counter++
                }
            }.bind(this)
        }
    }
}
let c = new Counter();
for (let i of c) console.log(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not direct equivalent. It's generator, not custom class with iteration.

Comment: See my modified answer

Comment: It's not the same, - you still can't do for (i of myCustomClass).

Comment: @NitzanTomer the last example in 2nd edit still doesn't work. Typescript does not have support for this. It gives an error saying `c is not an array or string type`. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: @sasidhar The last example requires es6 features. If you compile it with `-t es6` it will work just fine.

Comment: @NitzanTomer is there a way to do this when we are targeting es5 ?

Comment: @sasidhar If you're not compiling `es6` then it might not work in the runtime environment. If you are sure that it will work at runtime and you only have problems compiling,  then you might want to try a combination of the `--lib` flag that will make it work. Another option is to cast it to: `c as any as number[]`

Answer (score 18):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38508459/1041641) will only work for a single iteration (thus it can also not support nested iterations) and the worst thing is that it will enter an endless loop when you try to iterate again.

here's a version that fixes these issues:

```js
class Counter implements Iterable<number> {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        let counter = 0;
        return {
            next: () => {
                return {
                    done: counter >= 5,
                    value: counter++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- whenever an iterator is requested, we return an iterator with `count=0`
- each iteration will increase the closure variable `counter` until we are done

now multiple iterations work:

```js
let c = new Counter();
for (let i of c) console.log(i);
for (let i of c) console.log(i);
```

and nested iterations also works:

```js
let c = new Counter();
for (let i of c) {
    console.log('OUTER', i);
    for (let i of c) {
        console.log('--inner', i);
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BXAdgFwKYCdoEsC2ADiOnumjAJIaZgBGxAPMonrVgHzQDeAUNP9ADaAZQCereCAB0OamFTxMAXQAUASm58B24qmjAkaLNAC80AAwBuLdv6Z0qRJmSbbb6MnQAPVAC5o6qacvO6h0PaOzq5hMQAm8J7+BijU0OxmAKwANDYx7gBuYCCI6EmG1ADUFbl50AC+Ne4Noc0CDQ26+qYe6ADucOVY6tYAZooBnTjQ8CP6GgbIEJLoUiDwAOYqOGqj4yqT07PA8wlLxKsbWzs8PGPY+w64h3PR-AtnK2ubAOQA8gCqABUAKIAJW+WVw120dwmjymMxeIXc72WFx+AFoMThkJ5MBCodZtO0gA)

### Generator function

An alternative is to use a generator function which results in shorter code (see [Krisztián Ballas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73670321/1041641)):

```js
class Counter implements Iterable<number> {
    *[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<number> {
        let counter = 0;
        while (counter < 5) {
            yield counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BXAdgFwKYCdoEsC2ADiOnumjAJIaZgBGxAPMonrVgHzQDeAUNP9ABUAbQDKAT1bwQAOhzUwqeJgC6ACgCUALmhUsdYnppLMTFm0ydeAm9GKpowJGizQAvNAAMAbj63%20AO4AFjjE0GpOKNTQDNAArBrcfv424jjoIAAmjs7UANR5vinQAL7JpTxlPPaO7tDI6AFwuViavgBmyuE1ONDw7Y6JTsgQ0ugyIPAA5mo4Gh1daj19A8BD8CNjE9Oz8zw8ndhL6A69-YNJNsOjxNszAOQA8gCqACoAogBK9wA0uHs2Q7dE64FYXawpa5bSYPAC0sJwyAamF%20-yKAjKJSAA)

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have a simple class that wraps a string object:

```
class StringWrapper {
    private readonly wrappedString: string;

    public constructor(str: string) {
        this.wrappedString = str;
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<string> {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.wrappedString.length; ++i) {
            yield this.wrappedString[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The iterator is a generator function which yields one character after another from the wrapped string.

Now you can do things like this:

```
const wstr = new StringWrapper("abcd");

for (const char of wstr) {
    console.log(char); // will output "a", "b", "c", "d" separately
}

const anotherString == [..wstr]; // will be "abcd"
```

Comment: Really nice! I have updated my answer to have a comparison of the generator function vs. the original answer. The generator function is more readable IMHO.