# Recommended way to implement Iterator<T> in Typescript, before ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, iterator, iterable

I have a project that includes many classes that ideally would implement the `Iterable<T>` and/or `Iterator<T>` interfaces. However I cannot seem to find a standard TypeScript definition of these interfaces (for example in typescript-collections or some similar package).

I understand these are somewhat standardized in ECMAScript 6 through the `Symbol.iterator` mechanism, but my target is ECMAScript 5 and will stay so for the foreseeable future.

Can I somehow get these interfaces without defining them myself (for future compatibility with other modules, for example)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a duplicate of: [typescript: make class objects iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508172/typescript-make-class-objects-iterable), but here's an answer to `ES5`:

You want to use a [`ES6` feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

> One addition of ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) is not new syntax or a new
>   built-in, but a protocol. This protocol can be implemented by any
>   object respecting some conventions.
>
> There are two protocols: The iterable protocol and the iterator
>   protocol.

In a `ES5` environment (compilation and/or runtime), and that's not something that you can do.
With that being said, you can get close enough [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators):

> An object is an iterator when it knows how to access items from a
>   collection one at a time, while keeping track of its current position
>   within that sequence. In JavaScript an iterator is an object that
>   provides a next() method which returns the next item in the sequence.
>   This method returns an object with two properties: done and value.

So you can just return an object with a `next` method and it's an iterator:

```
class Counter /* implements Iterator<number> */ {
    private counter = 0;

    //public next(): IteratorResult<number> {
    public next(): { done: boolean, value: number } {
        return {
            done: false,
            value: this.counter++
        }
    }
}

let c = new Counter();
console.log(c.next().value); // 0
console.log(c.next().value); // 1
console.log(c.next().value); // 2
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Counter%20%2F*%20implements%20Iterator%3Cnumber%3E%20*%2F%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20counter%20%3D%200%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fpublic%20next()%3A%20IteratorResult%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20next()%3A%20%7B%20done%3A%20boolean%2C%20value%3A%20number%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20done%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20this.counter%2B%2B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20new%20Counter()%3B%0Aconsole.log(c.next().value)%3B%20%2F%2F%200%0Aconsole.log(c.next().value)%3B%20%2F%2F%201%0Aconsole.log(c.next().value)%3B%20%2F%2F%202))

The commented out parts will work with target `ES6` but not when it's below that.
But if your runtime environment does support this feature then the compiled js will do the job just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I was looking for was some sort of typescript pre-ES6 standard, but it seems that doesn't exist. For example if I'd like to implement a `sort(collection: Iterable<E>)` I would have to define the `Iterable` interface myself, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but if you're using the name `Iterable` then you need to think about what happens when you do move to `ES6` and that interface already exists.