# How to override the key iterator in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, typescript, iterator

I have this typescript class (reduced for simplicity):

```
class Dictionary<T> {

    items = [];

    add(item: T) {
        this.items.push(item);
    }

    ... more code here ...

}
```

When I instantiate  a variabel

```
var channels = new Dictionary<Channel>();
channels.add(new Channel('name1'));
channels.add(new Channel('name2'));
```

In another part of code (**which I cannot change**) the object is used in a loop:

```
for (var key in channels){ console.log(key);}
```

I get "items", the member of my object whereas I want to get the content of the items array in the channels object.

So what I want in this case is

[0,1]  the keys of the items array.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this by implementing Iterator. That will allow you to dictate how loops over your object work.
Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508172/typescript-make-class-objects-iterable).

Possibly it will only be possible if you target ES6,
however [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968894/recommended-way-to-implement-iteratort-in-typescript-before-es6) seems to suggest you can just implement a next() method to make it work.

Comment: Iterators only work with for..of loops, not with for..in loops.  I cannot change the for..in loop, sadly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution but there is the `length` member:

```
class Dictionary<T> extends Array<T> {
    add(item: T) {
        this.push(item);
    }
}

class Channel {
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }
}

var channels = new Dictionary<Channel>();
channels.add(new Channel('name1'));
channels.add(new Channel('name2'));

console.log(Object.keys(channels)); // Array [ "0", "1", "length" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**: To get `value` of `object` through `key`
Try like this

```
for (var key in channels){ 
     console.log(channels[key]);
}
```

Comment: It is an arbitrary class... the Dictionary should be capable of holding any type of object.

Comment: Check this I tried with `String` `Dictionary ` http://jsbin.com/vivanigelo/edit?js,console

Comment: As said, this is not what I want. I cannot use "channels.items" in the loop (not in my code).

Comment: Can you try the updated answer. I mean is it possible for you to log `channels[key]`. It will give yo the `items` list

Comment: I updated my question to state that I cannot change anything to the loop statement, since it is not in my code.

Comment: Then where you will write your code to access `channels` object?